# oracle date field not evaluating in grails using java.Date

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy Oracle table mapped to a Domain class in Grails listed below:

```
class myDomain implements Serializable {

    String id
    String baseCountry
    Date expireDate

static constraints = {
}
static mapping = {
    version false
    autoTimestamp false
    datasource 'OraDataSource'
    table "MY_ACCOUNT"
    id column: "LICENSE_NUMBER", generator: "assigned"
    baseCountry column: "BASE_COUNTRY"
    expireDate column: "EXPIRE_DATE" NOTE:  This is an Oracle DATE type
}
```

I set up my Dates in Grails as shown below:

```
def now = new Date()
def currentYear = now[YEAR]
def expireDateBegin  = new Date()
def expireDateEnd = new Date()

expireDateBegin[YEAR] = currentYear
expireDateBegin[MONTH] = DECEMBER
expireDateBegin[DATE] = 30

expireDateEnd[YEAR] = currentYear +1
expireDateEnd[MONTH] = JANUARY
expireDateEnd[DATE] = 01
```

When I use a dynamic finder with a Date criteria no results are returned:

```
def iftaAccountInfo = 
    CTaxAccount.findByBaseCountryAndExpireDateBetween(
        country, 
        expireDateBegin, 
        expireDateEnd, 
        [max: 1, sort: "expireDate", order: "desc"])
```

If I use a dymanic finder with just the country, I can see the results and when looking at the debugger, the date is being cast as a timestamp.

The SQL is correct when `logSql = true` is set, but something is going on with the Date when GORM sets the date in the query.  I can't figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I have also tried clearing the time with `Date().ClearTime()`. No change.

I am running Grails 2.3.4, OJDBC7.jar, and JDK 1.7_045.  The Oracle datsource is set to ReadOnly since this is legacy DB I am using for lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a reason to break the date up into pieces? I typically use the SimpleDateFormat class and manipulate the string received from the params object.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def country = params.country
String strExpireDateBegin, strExpireDateEnd

//This is dependent on what values you're passing to your service.
strExpireDateBegin = (params.startDate == null)?"":params.expireDateBegin
strExpireDateEnd = (params.endDate == null)?"":params.expireDateEnd

//This would be how I would generate the expiration date a year from the expireBeginDate
Date expireDateBegin = new Date()
Date expireDateEnd = expireDateBegin + 365


***use this for rendering the string into a Date***
Date expireDateBegin, expireDateEnd
expireDateBegin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(strExpireDateBegin)
expireDateEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(strExpireDateEnd)

***results = MyCriteria.list {
  and {
      country = myCountry
  }
  between("expireDate", expireDateBegin, expireDateEnd)
  order("expireDate", "desc")
}
```

***Bootstrap.groovy configuration for date rendering

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
        return it?.format("yyyy-MMM-dd")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure I tried this.  I think that when it parses the string back into dates, it has a time of 00:00:00.  I will give it a try though

Comment: The time on the date shouldn't matter, but if you need to format the date for UI purposes. You can edit the date rendered back using the following in your Bootstrap.groovy. I updated my answer to show you how to modify date.